# A book without chapter title (only in the header)

Tags: header-footer, titles

I want my chapters (all of them) to have no title displayed (they should appear only in the header). I found a solution somewhere on the forum that works (kinda). Here it is:

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{book}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{#1}{#1}}
\fancyhead[R]{\Large\leftmark}
\fancyhead[L]{}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\theme}[1]{%
  \begingroup
  \let\@makechapterhead\@gobble % make \@makechapterhead do nothing
  \chapter{#1}
  \endgroup
}
\makeatother

\renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{section}}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}[runin]{}{}{0pt}{\bfseries}
\titlespacing{\chapter}{0pt}{0pt}{0pt}
\titleclass{\chapter}{straight}
\newcommand{\chapterbreak}{\clearpage}
\titlespacing{\section}{0.0pt}{0.4cm}{0.0pt} 
\titleformat{\section}[runin]{}{\textbf{\thesection ) }}{0pt}{}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}

\theme{Theme 1}
\section{} blabla
\section{} blabla
\section{} blabla

\theme{Theme 2}
\section{} blabla

\theme{Theme 3}
\section{} blabla

\theme{Theme 4}
\section{} blabla

\end{document}
```

This code creates a new "chapter" class that I call "theme" and it does remove the titles... except not of every chapter. On this exemple it works only for the first chapter but, depending of the content of the chapters, sometimes the bug starts at chapter 5 or 6.

Any help would be welcome.

thanks

Comment: If you refer to some code you've found somewhere, it would be useful to have a link to that code.

Comment: You might try `\newcommand{\theme}[1]{\chapter[#1]{}}` instead.  The group might be losing some useful local information.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want a chapter title, I would suggest to not use `\chapter` but only `\chaptermark` (or `\markboth`/`\markright`) and `\addcontentsline`:

```latex
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{book}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{#1}{#1}}
\fancyhead[R]{\Large\leftmark}
\fancyhead[L]{}

\newcommand{\theme}[1]{%
  \clearpage
  % optional: \refstepcounter{chapter}
  \chaptermark{#1}%
  \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{#1}%
  % or \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\numberline{\thechapter}#1}
}

\renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{section}}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}[runin]{}{}{0pt}{\bfseries}
\titlespacing{\chapter}{0pt}{0pt}{0pt}
\titleclass{\chapter}{straight}
\newcommand{\chapterbreak}{\clearpage}
\titlespacing{\section}{0.0pt}{0.4cm}{0.0pt} 
\titleformat{\section}[runin]{}{\textbf{\thesection ) }}{0pt}{}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}

\theme{Theme 1}
\section{} blabla
\section{} blabla
\section{} blabla

\theme{Theme 2}
\section{} blabla

\theme{Theme 3}
\section{} blabla

\theme{Theme 4}
\section{} blabla

\end{document}
```

Note: Because of your changes to `\section` I've not removed `titlesec`. But it is not needed for the `\theme` command.

If the *themes* should be numbered, you can activate the `\refstepcounter` command and then use `\thechapter` for the number. Alternatively you could also define a new counter.